# pulltorefresh lib's SmartRefresher trigger CustomScrollView child component data update in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi I am a newbie about learning flutter,  now I am using `pull_to_refresh` lib to make my `CustomScrollView` pull to refresh. This is the [lib](https://github.com/peng8350/flutter_pulltorefresh):

```
pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.1
```

then using like this:

```
return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            bottom: false,
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return SmartRefresher(
                    onRefresh: _onRefresh,
                    enablePullUp: true,
                    enablePullDown: true,
                    controller: _refreshController,
                    onLoading: _onLoading,
                    footer: CustomFooter(
                      builder: (BuildContext context, LoadStatus mode) {
                        Widget body;
                        if (mode == LoadStatus.idle) {
                          body = Text("pull up load");
                        } else if (mode == LoadStatus.loading) {
                          //body =  CupertinoActivityIndicator();
                        } else if (mode == LoadStatus.failed) {
                          body = Text("Load Failed!Click retry!");
                        } else if (mode == LoadStatus.canLoading) {
                          body = Text("release to load more");
                        } else {
                          body = Text("No more Data");
                        }
                        return Container(
                          height: 55.0,
                          child: Center(child: body),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    child: CustomScrollView(
                      key: PageStorageKey(type),
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverOverlapInjector(
                          handle: NestedScrollView
                              .sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                            context,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SliverPadding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                          sliver: ArticlesPage(
                            type: type,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ));
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
```

now render CustomScrollView data in the sub component, this is the sub component `ArticlesPage` code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/component/loading_item.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/component/story_list.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/models/Item.dart';
import 'package:Cruise/src/common/Repo.dart';

final storiesTypeProvider = FutureProvider.family((ref, type) async {
  return await Repo.getArticles(type);
});

final storyProvider = FutureProvider.family((ref, id) async {
  return await Repo.fetchItem(id);
});

class ArticlesPage extends HookWidget {
  const ArticlesPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.type,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final StoriesType type;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      (context, read) {
        return read(storiesTypeProvider(type)).when(
          loading: () {
            return SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Center(child: LoadingItem()));
          },
          error: (err, stack) {
            print(err);
            return SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Center(child: Text('Error: $err')));
          },
          data: (ids) {
            return StoryList(ids: ids);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

now how to refresh child component data on parent trigger refresh code? to make it refresh, reinvoke the `storiesTypeProvider` function may work because in this api it always return the newest data from server side. I don't know how to trigger reinvoke and keep the refresh flow. Finally I found the `onrefresh` not triggered. But when I write it like this:

```
builder: (context) {
                    return SmartRefresher(
                        onRefresh: (){
                          print("trigger");
                        })
}
```

It could successfully trigger the action. If using function outer, it could not trigger.  this is the outer function define:

```
 void onRefresh() {
    // monitor network fetch
    //await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    // if failed,use refreshFailed()
    // topStories();
    storiesTypeProvider(StoriesType.topStories);
    _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
  }
```

why?

Comment: Have you tried calling storiesTypeProvider  in onRefresh property

Comment: Yes, I have tried this way, it seems not trigger the onRefresh function. @ismail